# Tag suggestion - without L'Hopital

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is a regular stream of questions asking for limits by elementary means - "without l'Hopital" (I've omitted the accent) - would this be a viable tag for questions?

My doubt is that it simply won't be used because people won't imagine such a thing could exist. On the other hand it would gather together a collection of similar questions, and might assist in the identification of duplicates.

---

Having read comments, here is a more concrete suggestion (is there a more concise description?)

limit-elementary-continuous

Limits of continuous functions without the use of calculus or related methods. In particular the evaluation of limits without using L'Hôpital's rule, and the limits of rational functions.

Elementary indicates no calculus allowed. Continuous avoids application of the tag to elementary limits of sums and series

Comment: It doesn't have to be the OP who tags the question with that tag. It should be enough if there are several people who know about it and are ready to add it when needed.

Comment: If it exists, it could be named (limits-without-lhospital), which has 24 characters. This way it will be automatically suggested when the users begins typing (limits). @JoonasIlmavirta In theory, yes. In practice, the tags that are not intuitive enough for the OP to add are either not used, or misused.

Comment: @CareBear, true. I always forget that in theory there is no difference between theory and practice, but in practice there is... More seriously: Since tags are suggested in the order of frequency, it might be a good idea to add the new tag retroactively to some old posts to bring it higher. There are not many tags beginning with "limit" now, but it shouldn't be hard to bring it to top-3 where it's most visible.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I even have a [proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16883/147263) (with no support yet) that would help a bit: rename the (limit-theorems) tag.

Comment: One perk of creating this tag is that we could subsequently ignore it.

Comment: How bout (inhopitable-limits)? :)

Comment: I'd think that "limits without l'Hopital" would fall under the "alternative-proof" tag.

Comment: @Semiclassical: It would also fall under "calculus", but that doesn't mean we can't get more specialized tags.

Comment: In the concrete suggestion just added it says "no calculus".   But many of the "without l'Hopital"  limits are still solved with calculus, e.g., using Taylor polynomials, or the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That needs a rethink then - it isn't at all easy to capture the idea in a useful way.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "Limits without the use of calculus". If one is finding a limit, one **is** doing calculus, because the concept of limit is a part of calculus.

Comment: Does the suggested tag entail also the questions which are currently tagged as ([tag:epsilon-delta])? (If I read "limits without l'Hopital", then this seems to be substantially different from (epsilon-delta). If I read "limits using elementary means", then this description could include also the (epsilon-delta) type of questions.)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I'd prefer the accent being written out as the "s" it replaces. So, (inhospitable-limits), which might leak over to http://travel.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More of an announcement than an answer (I'm quite undecided about the tag suggestion as a whole, but am not really active in any related tags), but a [limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital) tag has recently been created. It currently has a tag excerpt but not a tag wiki, and only a few questions have been so tagged.

Comment: Thanks, we'll see how it goes.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I don't really want to admit it, but I didn't actually _do_ anything apart from posting this answer. Someone created the tag, I saw it in the list of new tags, I remembered this thread, and decided to post an answer instead of either posting a comment or editing the question. (So any thanks is _entirely_ undeserved.)

Comment: I created the tag based on this thread, actually. I didn't know what to write for the tag wiki at the time and figured someone more attuned to such things could do a much better than I ever could.