# Relating to create a new tag

Tags: support, tagging, deletion

I have created a tag named "significance" and gave the full details (all of them are approved by others after some time) and also I fit there 8 questions (different authors posted in different different time). After some hours when I want to see the status, I saw my tag was deleted without giving any kind of  explanation. Can any one help me to find out what happen

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Here is [link to the relevant entry](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/30415#30415) in the tag management thread. The tag was also [mentioned in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/6/27) (as are most newly created tags).

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: I should say that I am also unhappy about [tag:singular-solution] as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the fact that there is [a separate post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/30415#30415) in the Tag Management Thread, let me mention here some issues with this tag in more detail. (Several of them are probably more general comments - not specific just to this particular tag.)

The tag [significance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significance) was created and removed twice, first on [24 May 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/5/24) and again on [27 June 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/6/27); see also [the revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3238019/revisions) of the post where the tag was created. You can notice that the first removal was accompanied by the edit summary saying "Meta tags are discouraged, e.g. (coincidence)". Of course, I can imagine that users not familiar with the tagging system on this site might not know what the phrase *meta tags* means.

The OP also created [a tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3275661/revisions) and [a tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3275660/revisions). (This is certainly appreciated - many users who create a new tag neglect creating also the tag-info.)

The tag-excerpt said:

> This tag contains various questions relating to the "physical significance" or, "geometrical significance " or, "mathematical significance" of any term, expression, equation, graph etc. etc.

The tag-wiki said:

> Significance is not a formal term, but refers to an interpretation. It just means how you can interpret physically / geometrically / mathematically something about the topic under discussion.

- In general, it might be a good idea to discuss creation of a new tag on meta before actually doing so.<sup>1</sup> Remember that this site has been around for some time and in many cases it is reasonable to assume that somebody has thought about the tag you are suggesting already. You can notice that [the tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019) typically contains some tag suggestions. Or if you think that a more extensive discussion is needed, you can make a separate post. But even if you decide not to ask on meta, you can at least check whether the tag with the same name was discussed before. Or you could try to ask in the [tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3740/tagging).
- To discuss the tag creation on meta first is even more important if the tag in question is a meta tag.<sup>2</sup> By this I mean a tag which is not based on some area of mathematics or mathematical object, but by some other aspect of the question. Examples of meta tags are [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list), [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question), [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation), [motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation), etc. While some meta tags do exist on this site, it is better not to have too many tags of this kind. That's why we should be careful with creating new ones.
- In this particular case, the definition of the tag seems a bit unclear to me. Moreover, tags with a rather vague names are more likely to be used incorrectly.
- It's also good to avoid having many too specific tags - keep in mind that there is only space for five tags for a question. Based on the proposed description of the [significance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significance) tag, I can imagine a question where the tag would fit together with [motivation and intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation+intuition) - which would already take three out of five spaces.

<sup>1</sup>You can find some related discussion to this also here: [Should every new tag be discussed on meta before creation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17023)

<sup>2</sup>See also: [The “meta-tags”.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2498)