# Why is Umbral tag removed?

Tags: support, tagging

The tag feature of Math Stack Exchange seems to be a nice feature but I don't understand why some are allowed and some aren't.
For the example of [**umbral**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) calculus, I tried the "umbral" tag. I can understand that the **Sheffer sequences** or **Appell sequences** are removed because probably too specific. Is **umbral calculus** that rare? With my question, some else also posted a different question about it, so I think it is not that rare to be removed as a tag.

My question is:

> What are the requirements to create a new tag (power you acquire after 1000 points)? Does the frequency of a question matter or is it the importance of the field in research? How can people with 1000 points have access to data to make new tags correctly?

A side question being:

> Why was "umbral" calculus not allowed? For me it seems decently large to have its own tag.

Comment: In general, we want users to somehow discuss in advance the suitability of certain tags. This can take place here on meta (like now) or in the chatroom intended for discussing tagging.

Comment: Related to Asaf Karagila's comment: [Should every new tag be discussed on meta before creation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17023) (Most of [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/17023) are also related to creation of tags in some way or another.)

Comment: It is an interesting topic (to me), so it is a reasonable one to propose a tag for.  You have mentioned posting one question and seeing another one (by a different user) where this tag would be useful.  Linking to these would help the discussion here on Meta Math.SE.  The tag creation mechanism naturally has less activity after Math.SE has matured, but the auto-deletion of tags which are not associated with Questions remains an active feature.  Seeing examples would help Readers see what happened.  A proposed wikia for the tag would also help us to discuss.

Comment: It's also relevant to point out that there are already a substantial number of questions about umbral calculus with no particular tag in common. That's generally a good sign that a proposed tag would be useful.

Comment: I've added a [tag creation proposal](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31257/468350) to the 2020 Tag Management thread.