# limits-without-lhospital tag misspelled

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, retagging

It seems stemming from [this discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16916/221073) that the tag [limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital) was created.  Someone even [corrected](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/956394/3) the spelling of the name in the excerpt recently, but the title still reflects incorrect spelling (minus diacritics).

Suggest renaming the tag to [limits-without-lhopital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhopital), with a tag synonym of [limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital) to grab any possible misspellings.

Comment: Diacritics are not supported in tag names on math.SE (unfortunately). In French, the circumflex generally denotes that an 's' used to be there but has been removed, and it is indeed the case in "hôpital". Since we cannot put a circumflex in the tag name, the next best thing is to add an 's', IMO (and it is the opinion of many users here, as far as I know). It's the same for Kähler (the tag's name is [tag:kaehler-manifolds]), Möbius ([tag:moebius-function])... But I guess adding [tag:limits-without-lhopital] as a synonym couldn't hurt (and the whole tag wiki needs rewriting).

Comment: An older post about the same issue: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19060#19060

Comment: @MartinSleziak ah, good find.  btw, at that link i see the wikipedia-sourced comment by yes saying he spelled his name with an 's', and then there's [this book cover](https://ia600803.us.archive.org/zipview.php?zip=/35/items/olcovers602/olcovers602-L.zip&file=6023755-L.jpg) from 1768.  oh who to trust these days...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi of course, i was not suggesting there should be a tag with diacritics.  i'm not sure how easy it is to rename a tag, but semantically speaking, i think the misspelling ("s" version) should point to the non-"s" version, not the other way around.

Comment: My point is that it's not a misspelling, it's a transliteration. Gauss should really be called Gauß, but it's generally okay to call him Gauss because most people have no idea how to type an eszett anyway. I believe it's similar here. (Or put in a different light: "Hopital" is as much a misspelling as "Hospital", since the only correct spelling is "Hôpital" in modern French).

Comment: Note that the circumflex over a vowel denoting a lost "s" was [officially introduced into the 1740 edition of the dictionary of the Académie Française](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French#Indication_of_a_lost_phoneme). It is then not too surprising that the 1768 edition uses the more modern orthography with the circumflex. The [1716 edition](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jp7H4.png), however, uses "l'Hospital". Even this earlier edition is more than a decade after his death.

Comment: @ArthurFischer touche :)

Comment: Do you mean "touché"? :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi nope! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, I've taken [a previous suggestion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19060#comment69475_19060) to create a synonym [(limits-without-lhopital)](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limits-without-lhospital/synonyms) for [limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital).

(Now, do we need to introduce other synonyms: [limits-without-l-hospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-l-hospital), and [limits-without-l-hopital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-l-hopital)?)

Comment: Don't forget about the singular versions!